# Can I use company-licensed Software for private projects?

Tags: copyright, licensing

I got a Visual Studio 2019 Pro License at work, that is registered to my Work-Mail-Account. Now I was wondering if I could also install VS Pro with that license on my PC at home and create stuff with it, or is it restricted to my company / If I would create something, would it belong to my company then, if it's done with the license I got from work?

Comment: When in doubt, ask your company. Even if the licence allowed that use free of charge (which I really doubt), the company may object to it for whatever the reason. But there are Community (free) versions of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The license for Visual Studio 2019 Pro is per *user* not per device so you can install it on your home device - the example of a developer installing it on their home PC is even discussed in the [Licensing White Paper](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/Visual-Studio-Licensing-Whitepaper-Mar-2020.pdf):

> Example: A developer with a Visual Studio subscription uses subscriber software at work during the day, but occasionally
>   needs to develop at home as well, using a different computer. Under the Visual Studio subscription license, there is no
>   difference between a PC at work and a home PC; the home PC is just another device on which the developer is entitled
>   use the subscriber software.
>   However, the restrictions for the subscriber software running on the developer’s home PC remain the same as in the work
>   environment: the subscriber software installed on the home PC must only be used for design, development and testing
>   purposes; and only other users with an appropriate Visual Studio subscription can use the software.

But that's not the only concern you might have here - the license remains the property of your employer, and therefore any work you do with it is the same as using any other company resources or tools and that might give them some claim over anything developed using it. It's not unusual for employment contracts to explicitly say that any Intellectual Property created using it's resources belongs to it - but even in the absence of such a clause it doesn't mean they couldn't pursue some form of claim or otherwise make things uncomfortable for you.